# formula for counting the number of times each text appears in a column

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula that will count the number of times each text appears in column A then report the number in Col B.

For example:

```
Col A  Col B
 ABC     2
 ABC
 CDE     3
 CDE
 CDE 
 GHI     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in B2:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,COUNTIF(A:A,A2),"")
```

[image]